# Rule movement/promotion across environment (say UAT to Production environment)

Tags: drools

We are new to Drools rule engine. Can anyone guide us how the rule promotion is handled from one environment to another?

Say, in UAT environment, business users have created the rules and verified the same. If we want to move those rules to production environment then what is the suggested process for the same. We heard that the rules are stored in git repository from Drools work bench. Do we need to use that git repository to promote rules form one environment to other ? If yes, then what are the steps ? we need to move, selective rules from one environment to other. Or there ware options like export from one environment's workbench (uat environment) and import the rules in other workbench (production) environment? Any automation available?

Or selective rules can be directly compiled from one environment (UI and/or script)  and deployed in the KIE rules execution server in another environment?

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards
SR

Comment: Did you try Jenkins for automation?

Comment: We are pretty new to Drools. Can you please let us know that is there any plugin in jenkins specific to drools ? We are looking for best possible option to automate the rules movement from one environment to other in Drools. Is there any guide available?

Comment: Are you using Drools Work Bench or running them from your own application? It's not really clear how your project or deployment environment are set up. As it stands, your question is really broad.

Comment: We are planning to use it from Business Central/Drools workbench and call the rules through RESTful services from application. So, we are looking for CI/CD based integration of the rules (probably kjar) in other environments. i.e a possible option we are trying to find is:  from Drools git repository (using some tag) the CI/CD tool can fetch the selected rules, pack it in KJAR (Knowledge jar)  and deploy it in production KIE execution server. Is it a correct option we are thinking ? If yes, is there any detailed documentation to integrate with CI/CD (say jenkins) to do such option ?